# Passing Parameters of a Function React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, payload, recharts

In my application, I want to conditionally render something, so I made a function `getItem` which I want to call in my custom Tooltip, `const CustomTooltip`.

Seen in the code below, I want to pass `payload` in `const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label}` to `function getState({payload}`

I try to do this by `{getState(payload, "A")}` However, when I do so, I get this error:

Type 'Payload<ValueType, NameType>[]' has no properties in common with type 'TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>'

Note: I am new to React

```
  const numberStates = 3;
  function getState({payload}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>, state: string ){
    if(payload){
      for(let i = 0; i < numberStates; i++){
        if(payload[i].dataKey == state){
          return <p>{ payload[i] } : { payload[i].value }</p>
        }
      }
    }
    return null;
  }

  const CustomTooltip = ({ active, payload, label}: TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>) => {
    if(active && payload && payload.length){
      return (
        <div className = "custom-tooltip">
          {getState(payload, "A")}
          {getState(payload, "B")}
          {getState(payload, "C")}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Please show deifinition of TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>

Comment: @AndriusOlišauskas Tooltip and TooltipProps are imports from recharts, the definition is long, here is some of it: export declare type TooltipProps<TValue extends ValueType, TName extends NameType> = DefaultProps<TValue, TName> & {
    allowEscapeViewBox?: {
        x?: boolean;
        y?: boolean;
    };    content?: ContentType<TValue, TName>;
    viewBox?: {
        x?: number;
        y?: number;
        width?: number;
        height?: number;
    };

Comment: An aside: it'd be more idiomatic to make the function getState a component.

Comment: @RobertP could you please elaborate as to why that would be better?

Comment: React is all about a functional transformation of data into HTML. the `getState` function is effectively a component since it returns a react node. Every time the code does that, you should think "I need to turn this into a react component". It's not a perfect analogy, but it's like saying "why drive on the side of the road that everyone else drives on?" Well, it's the convention. Technically yeah you could drive on the other side. But people don't, because people expect it, if you didn't people would question your driving, and it might confuse others and cause accidents.

Answer (score -1):

You are passing **payload** which is of type: **Payload<ValueType, NameType>[]**
But in **getState** function you expect **TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>**

Change code to this:

```
function getState(payload: Payload<ValueType, NameType>[], state: string) {
  if (payload) {
    for (let i = 0; i < numberStates; i++) {
      if (payload[i].dataKey === state) {
        return (
          <p>
            {payload[i]} : {payload[i].value}
          </p>
        );
      }
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: when I change the code to this, I get error: Property 'payload' does not exist on type 'TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType>[]'

Comment: Which part of code throws this error? The reason the type needs to be changed in getState function argument is that you are passing argument payload which is destructured in CustomTooltip props. 
TooltipProps<ValueType, NameType> = { payload: Payload<ValueType, NameType>[] }
So in the end getState received payload property, not whole tooltip object.

Comment: I get an error on the function getState(payload: Payload<ValueType, NameType>[], state: string) line

Comment: Please update your question to show your latest code, that might help. :)